# Power series representation

Tags: power-series

Im trying to find the function whose power series is given by $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x  (x-1)^n$
So according to me $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+(x-1)} $
Which is nothing but $ f(x) = 1  $
Is it right?

I'm using standard representation of  $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)} $
I want to find value of  $f(\pi/4)$ where $ 0<x<2$

Comment: I don't understand the sentence “I want to find value of $f(\pi/4)$ where $0<x<2$”, since there is not $x$ in $f(\pi/4)$. By the way, $f(\pi/4)=1$, of course.

Comment: Yes you're right the answer is 1 but i just wanted to confirm my $f(x)$ is it right or not? By the way thanks for comment i love your explanations.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.